# how to detect minimum rotation in a JavaScript gesture library (eg alloyfinger.js)

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I have a mobile web app written in JavaScript, using alloyfinger.js.

I tried Hammer.js, but it didn't work with certain iPhone models (eg iPhone 7+).

I suspect my question is the same for various gesture detection libraries.

My app detects rotate events, but I can't seem to write the correct code to ignore rotate events below a minimum angle of rotation.  The code below hides the rotated element, even when the amount of rotation is very small.

```
handleRotatEvent(evt) {
    const angle = evt.angle;

    const absAngle = Math.abs(angle);

    const minAngle = (90 * Math.PI / 180);
    // convert 90 degrees to radians

    if (absAngle < minAngle)
        return;

    hideItem(evt);
    // use the event to find the target DOM element and hide it
}
```

My intent is to ignore rotations smaller than 90 degrees.  Otherwise, hide the rotated element.

What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Adam Leffert
https://www.leffert.com

Answer (score 0):

@dntzhang, the author of AlloyFinger.js answered this question on Twitter.  He said that the angle resets as the user rotates the element.  My more fundamental intent was to detect small rotations as a way to distinguish rotate events from swipe or pan events.  He said that the correct way to do that is to check the number of fingers touching the element.  One for swipe or pan.  Two for rotate.  Much simpler.